# How to prove that $e_{q_1}(x)>e_{q_2}(x)$ for $q_1>q_2$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, q-analogs

I am struggling with a simple inequality with $q$-exponential functions.

We call $q$-exponential function the following expansion serie :

$$e_q(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n \frac{(1-q)^n}{(1-q^n)(1-q^{n-1})...(1-q)}.$$

My question is, from the expansion form of the $q$-exponential, if $q_1>q_2>0$, how to prove that for all $x$ positive we have :

$$e_{q_1}(x)>e_{q_2}(x).$$

Any help would be appreciated since I have no clue to handle this question. Thank you very much.

Comment: Of course, you are totaly right. I have just added it.

Comment: $(1-q)/(1-q^k)$ is decreasing. The inequality should be reversed.